# 5 Day Forecast Date Not Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, date

When 5 cards are created for the 5-day weather forecast, the icon, temp, and humidity data are correct, but the date stays the same on all five cards. Any idea why? Thank you!
UPDATE: I added "if-sentence" realizing that the data I get is for every few hours so that`s the reason my cards all have the same date. This syntax seems logical to me, but it ends up giving me only one card. I hope someone can spot the error in my code. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on("click", function() {
    var userInput = $("#user-input").val();
    fiveDayForecast(userInput);
  });

  var key = 'my API key';
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";

  function fiveDayForecast(userInput) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        q: userInput,
        appid: key,
        units: "imperial",
        cnt: "5"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#five-day-forecast").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
         if(data.list[i].dt_txt.indexOf("15:00:00") !== -1) {
          var colEl = $("<div>").addClass("col col-lg-2");
          var cardEl = $("<div>").addClass("card text-white bg-primary m-3");
          var cardBody = $("<div>").addClass("card-body");
          var cardTitle = $("<h5>").addClass("card-title").text(new Date(data.list[i].dt_txt).toLocaleDateString());
          var img = $("<img>").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.list[i].weather[0].icon + ".png");
          var cardText1 = $("<p>").addClass("card-text").text("Temp: " + data.list[i].main.temp_max + " °F");
          var cardText2 = $("<p>").addClass("card-text").text("Humidity: " + data.list[i].main.humidity + "%");
          colEl.append(cardEl.append(cardBody.append(cardTitle, img, cardText1, cardText2)));
          $("#five-day-forecast").append(cardEl);
         }
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Sample data:

```
"list":[ 
  { "dt":1595840400, "main":{}, "weather":[], "clouds":{}, "wind":{}, "visibility":10000, "pop":0.66, "rain":{}, 
    "sys":{}, "dt_txt":"2020-07-27 09:00:00" 
  },
   ...
]
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing the content of `data`, or at the very least `data.list[i].dt_txt`

Comment: "list":[
      {
         "dt":1595840400,
         "main":{},
         "weather":[],
         "clouds":{},
         "wind":{},
         "visibility":10000,
         "pop":0.66,
         "rain":{},
         "sys":{},
         "dt_txt":"2020-07-27 09:00:00"
      },

Comment: I know where the problem is. Every next object shows the weather in a few hours, not the following day, so all my five cards have slightly different data but it`s still the same day. I am not sure how to skip to the next day? I guess it would be if statement, but not sure about the exact way?

Comment: Don't put additional information in comments, add it to the OP.